# Issue with selenium By.xpath when concatenating several findElement calls

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am having a problem understanding the semantic of Selenium for the following chain of calls.

```
WebElement row = driver.findElement(MyBy.tableRowContent("Selenium"));
WebElement editIcon = row.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Edit']"));
```

I thought when calling findElement on a WebElement, the query would be narrowed to the ancestor document (row in my previous example). This doesn't seem to be the standard mechanism when using Xpath. The previous call is using the whole DOM and not the given ancestor.

If I want to narrow the second call to the row WebElement I have to modify the xpath query as follows (note the dot at the beginning of the query):

```
WebElement editIcon = row.findElement(MyBy.xpath(".//span[@title='Edit']"));
```

For the sake of comparing, the following works fine when using css selectors:

```
WebElement row = driver.findElement(MyBy.tableRowContent("Selenium"));
WebElement editIcon = row.findElement(MyBy.cssSelector("span[title='Edit']"));
```

**Is this the expected behavior or is it a problem with the By.xpath implementation?**

Answer (score 4):

This is the *expected (and confusing) behavior* - the dot at the beginning of the expression makes the search context-specific - without the dot XPath expression is "absolute" and the search would be started from the root element of the DOM tree.

But, yes, this is sometimes really confusing, since it's difficult to think about a reason why would you want to perform a search from the root while calling "find element by xpath" on a specific element. Here is a related issue with some good points:

- [Selenium webdriver finds only descendant nodes for find_elements(:xpath) when asked for all nodes](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=403)

Comment: Then this means that there is no difference in concatening findElement calls when using Xpath queries. Shall I conclude that all the Xpath queries are global to the DOM?

Comment: @narko nope, you should just always keep in mind to put the dot before the xpath expressions if you mean to find elements relative to the current. If you put a dot, you'll have a relative expression, the search would be performed in the context of the current element.

Comment: After reading the link that you sent I saw that the original implementation was done without the '.', just like I would expect. In my opinion it was right the way it was, now it is confusing unless you know explicitly that Selenium needs the dot to use the current context. It would be great if someone could add that to the existing documentation : http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

Comment: @narko yeah, I think you are right, the documentation does not explicitly tell about this particular problem.

Comment: This saved me some headaches many years later, thanks you!